# Android: How can I close application after a toast message disappear?

Tags: android, toast

Just as the title says. I'm trying to have display a Toast text when a button is clicked, and then close the application after the message disappears.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

finish();
```

This closes the application as the toast message displays and I was just wondering if I could delay closing the application to after the message disappears.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend not using a toast for this. It doesn't make that much sense. Just show something in the activity for whatever period of time you like before finishing it.

Comment: @Mikedg, why doesn't it make sense? My app requires network connection. Instead of just exiting the app when the user doesn't have connection, I want to let them save a message (locally) that will be sent to the server the next time he/she opens the app with a connection. I just want to display something like "message saved" and then finish the app. I thought using toast was good enough.

Comment: Well in that case, no other app on the platform waits for the toast to go away before finishing the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set a timer for the time it takes the toast to disappear.
If I'm not mistaken, LENGTH_SHORT is 2 seconds or around it.
Call a timer with a timer task with a 2 seconds delay that will call finish in turn.

Comment: According to API docs those lengths are user definable, although no evice that I'm aware of allows them to be changed.

Comment: I don't see how they are user definable (at least not in the current common API levels). These are constants in the Toast class code and there is no method to define a different length.

Comment: Yeah, there's no current way of changing it that I'm aware of but the docs do say "This time could be user-definable."

Comment: Also, check that the user did not leave the activity or start some other operation during that 2 seconds or you could wind up calling finish on an invalid Activity.